# PySpark import statements running for a very long time

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, bigdata

My PySpark code is below, and the first part, i.e, the import statements cell takes a very long time to run in Jupyter, in fact, the execution didn't happen till 5 - 6 hours, and later it shows a "Time limit exceeded error".

I have tried everything, like restarting jupyter, uninstalling anaconda, and then reinstalling, uninstalling spark and pyspark, and then re-installing both of them again. I even removed python completely and then installed it again, BUT THE PROBLEM NEVER SOLVED...!

**Edit 1:-** I realized that the problem is with the line `spark = init_spark()`  This is taking a lot of time to run (in fact not running even after 4 - 5 hours)
Please help me with this...

```
import os
import sys
import pyspark
from pyspark.rdd import RDD
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import functions
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, desc, col, size
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
import matplotlib
from pylab import *
import scipy.stats as stats

# This helps auto print out the items without explixitly using 'print'
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all" 

# Initialize a spark session.

conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]")
def init_spark():
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Statistical Inferences with Pyspark") \
        .config(conf=conf) \
        .getOrCreate()
    return spark

spark = init_spark()
filename_data = 'D:\Subjects\ARTIFICIAL INTELLIGENCE\SEMESTER - 5\Big Data and DataBase Management\End Sem Project\endomondoHR_proper.json'
df = spark.read.json(filename_data, mode="DROPMALFORMED")

# Load meta data file into pyspark data frame as well
print('Data frame type: {}'.format(type(df)))
```

Comment: Hi! How big is `endomondoHR_proper.json` ?

Comment: how about restarting Jupyter and try again?

Comment: endomondoHR_proper.json is around 5 GB.

Comment: I have tried everything, like restarting jupyter, uninstalling anaconda, and then reinstalling, uninstalling spark and pyspark, and then re-installing both of them again. I even removed python completely and then installed it again, BUT THE PROBLEM NEVER SOLVED...!

Comment: I don't think it is the problem with the dataset, as I've seen my friends working on bigger datasets of sizes ranging from 10 GB to 40 GB, where they were easily able to parse them in seconds...